# Update object spring hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects from same type. One comes from data base and the second from other context. Now I like to update the values from the first one with the values from the second object. I use hibernate for the ORM. What is best practice for the following scenario

```
Class A{
  int id;
  String name;
} 
A obj1= session.get(A.class, 1);
A obj2 = differnetContext();
```

The first option:

```
obj1.setName(obj2.getName());
session.update(obj1)
```

The second option:

```
obj2.setId(obj1.getId());
session.update(obj2)
```

Exists there some function `leftmerge(obj1,obj2).exclude("id")` which returns a object of type A where name=world and id=1 that I can pass to the update process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scope of the transaction to your service level method using @Transactional then update the "live" entity you get from the database.

For example:

```
@Transactional
public void editUser(int userId, User editUser) {
    User liveUser = getUserDAO().findByPrimaryKey(userId);
    liveUser.setNameFirst(editUser.getNameFirst());
    liveUser.setNameLast(editUser.getNameLast());
    liveUser.setEmail(editUser.getEmail());
}
```

If you want associated entities to be updated as well then you can use cascade rules.  Lets say the user in this class has a OnetoOne association with an Address.  Then you can use the same approach if you have the set the CascadeType appropriately.

Expanded example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

   // user properties

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

}
```

Service level method...

```
@Transactional
public void editUser(int userId, User editUser) {
    User liveUser = getUserDAO().findByPrimaryKey(userId);
    liveUser.setNameFirst(editUser.getNameFirst());
    liveUser.setNameLast(editUser.getNameLast());
    liveUser.setEmail(editUser.getEmail());
    liveUser.setAddress(editUser.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, till now I do it as you described.